# gdb Python API: exceptions disappearing?

Tags: gdb, gud, gdb-python

Does anyone know why, in certain places, Python code inside of gdb doesn't properly handle exceptions?  Or, to clarify, perhaps the exception message
is going somewhere other than the *gud buffer.  gdb is not returning control
to the prompt, as expected.

(I'm using GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.50.20160212-git in Emacs (24.5.1) gud mode)

For example:

```
class SomeEvent():
   def __init__(self, ...):
      ... do something ...
   def __call__(self):
      ... do something BAD here ...


gdb.post_event(SomeEvent())
```

When 'SomeEvent' is handled, it will just execute '__call__' up to the bad code, return, and then continue normal operation (as I can observe).

I've noticed this behavior in other 'callback' type methods, such as Stop() of a subclassed gdb.Breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gdb.post_event` ignores exceptions when the event object is invoked.  You can see this clearly in the source code, in `gdbpy_run_events`:

```
  /* Ignore errors.  */
  call_result = PyObject_CallObject (item->event, NULL);
  if (call_result == NULL)
    PyErr_Clear ();
```

This seems like a bug to me -- it would be more useful to print a stack trace or something instead.

Comment: I was hoping you'd comment, Tom!  Thanks for giving me a clue on the source.  Yes, it would be better to show _something_